# In-place Array modification followed by usage Verifiable C

Tags: verifiable-c

VST 1.7, Coq 8.5pl2.

I have a global array *processedQVars* which I've called a function on to do an in-place modification, changing the SEP condition from

```
data_at Ews (tarray tint 8)
      (map Vint
         [Int.repr 15; Int.repr 5463; Int.repr 12; Int.repr 75; Int.repr 231; Int.repr 1431; 
         Int.repr 735; Int.repr 134]) processedQVals
```

with the array of Int.repr calls being a declared *processedQVals_contents* variable, to

```
data_at Ews (tarray tint 8)
      (map Vint (fold2 Int.xor (map Int.repr processedQVals_contents) (Int.repr 4231))) processedQVals
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm then trying to call another function on this array via *forward_call*. The tactic produces this (obviously unprovable) goal. The functional specification precondition is below, followed by the unprovable goal:

```
Definition checkArray_spec :=
  DECLARE _checkArray
WITH signedBits: val, originalBits: val, sh: share, 
     signedContents : list Z, originalContents : list Z, invKey : Z, size: Z
PRE [ _signedBits OF (tptr tint), _originalBits OF (tptr tint), _invKey OF tint, _size OF tint ]
      PROP  (readable_share sh; writable_share sh; 0 <= size < Int.max_signed; 
             size = Zlength signedContents; size = Zlength originalContents; 
             Forall (fun bit => Int.min_signed <= bit <= Int.max_signed) signedContents; 
             Forall (fun bit => Int.min_signed <= bit <= Int.max_signed) originalContents)
      LOCAL (temp _signedBits signedBits; temp _originalBits originalBits; 
             temp _invKey (Vint (Int.repr invKey)); temp _size (Vint (Int.repr size)))
      SEP   ((data_at sh (tarray tint size) (map Vint (map Int.repr signedContents)) signedBits);
             (data_at sh (tarray tint size) (map Vint (map Int.repr originalContents)) originalBits))

data_at Ews (tarray tint 8) (map Vint (fold2 Int.xor (map Int.repr processedQVals_contents) (Int.repr 4231)))
  processedQVals
|-- data_at Ews (tarray tint 8) (map Vint (map Int.repr processedQVals_contents)) processedQVals *
    fold_right sepcon emp Frame
```

Do I have to change the SEP clause in the precondition, or is there a way to change the call to *forward_call* to deal with it?

Thanks

Comment: What's the pre-condition of the second function call? Assume it's something like `data_at sh (tarray tint size) (map Vint content) v`, you should be able to pass `(fold2 Int.xor (map Int.repr processedQVals_contents) (Int.repr 4231))` as `content` in your `forward_call` tactic to proceed with your proof.

Comment: I thought for sure I had tried that, but apparently not, just had to convert that to a list Z and then it worked thanks.